# Why AccessControlException on ServerSocket.accept() when java.policy grants SocketPermission?

Tags: java

An AccessControlException is thrown on ServerSocket.accept() despite granting SocketPermission in java.policy.

For redaction purposes, lets say the server IP address is 1.2.3.4 and the client IP address is 5.6.7.8.

java.policy on the server has a grant.

```
grant codeBase "file:C:/workspaces/gitlab/QMT-beachhead/QMT-beachhead/lib/-"{
  permission java.net.SocketPermission "5.6.7.8:1024-", "accept";
};
```

The same effect has been attempted several of other ways:

```
permission java.net.SocketPermission "5.6.7.8", "accept";
permission java.net.SocketPermission "5.6.7.8:*", "accept";
permission java.net.SocketPermission "5.6.7.8:0", "accept";
```

The most recent attempt added the missing slash before the drive letter.

```
file:/C:/workspaces/gitlab/QMT-beachhead/QMT-beachhead/lib/-
```

All result in something like:

java.security.AccessControlException access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "5.6.7.8:50838" "accept,resolve")

The port in the server-side error message, understood to be the return value  from the client-side expression client.getLocalPort(), is different each time.

On the server,

```
private java.net.ServerSocket server;
private java.net.Socket connection;

try {
  connection = server.accept();
  }
catch (SecurityException e) {
  System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage());
}
```

On the client

```
private java.net.Socket client;
private java.io.ObjectInputStream input;

try {
  byte[] addr = {(byte)1, (byte)2, (byte)3, (byte)4};
  client = new java.net.Socket(java.net.InetAddress.getByAddress(addr), 16838);
  java.io.InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
  input = new ObjectInputStream(is);
}
  catch (java.io.IOException e) {
  System.err.println(e.getClass().getName());
}
```

The actual results are java.security.AccessControlException on the server while the accept method blocks, and java.io.EOFException on the client when instantiating ObjectInputStream from the java.io.InputStream, which is a java.net.SocketInputStream. Although EOFException is thrown from the ObjectInputStream constructor, it is the client's instantiation of Socket that triggers the server's AccessControlException.

The expected result is that the java.net.SocketPermission grant in the server's java.policy is understood, that there be no AccessControlException and that instantiating ObjectInputStream on the client from a java.io.InputStream, which is a java.net.SocketInputStream, is successful.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with a permission entry like

```
permission java.net.SocketPermission "5.6.7.8:1024-", "accept";
```

The codeBase value required more attention. The owner of 1.2.3.4 had verified that the code source location was in directory tree

```
C:\workspaces\gitlab\QMT-beachhead\QMT-beachhead\lib\
```

Some code was there, but the code that needed the SocketPermission was in directory tree

```
C:\workspaces\gitlab\QMT-beachhead\QMT-beachhead\bin\
```

Also, according to the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html#FileSyntax, a slash is required before the drive letter. The codeBase field becomes

```
codeBase "file:/C:/workspaces/gitlab/QMT-beachhead/QMT-beachhead/bin/-"
```